# Ĉu "iri sole" aŭ "iri sola"?

Tags: translation

Saluton. Duolingo tradukas l'anglan frazon "You are afraid of going alone." al "Vi timas iri **sola**.", sed mi kredas ke tio estas malĝusta, kaj oni devas traduki la frazon al "Vi timas iri **sole**.", ĉar mi pensas ke la vorto "alone" en la frazo estas adverbo, ne adjektivo. Kiel vi pensas pri tio?

Comment: Mi kredas ke Duolingo pravas pri tiu frazo. Estas bona klarigo pri la diferenco inter la du frazoj en ĉi tiu respondo al rilata demando https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/a/181/13

Comment: Dankon pro via respondo, Sinjoro Roberts. Sed mi pensas ke tiu ĉi frazo estas malsama al la frazo tie. En la ligilo, la frazo "Mia onklo venas sane." estas sensignifa ĉar oni ne povas veni sane aŭ malsane, sed en tiu ĉi frazo "iri sole" havas signifon laŭlogike. Tie, oni ne povas uzi adverbon pro la verbo "veni"; sed ĉi tie oni povas uzi adverbon pro la verbo "iri".

Comment: La ekzemploj en la respondo uzas la vortojn “sole” kaj “sola”, ĝuste ĉar “iri sane” ne havas sencon.

Comment: Pardonon Sinjoro Roberts, sed mi ne povis kompreni vian lastan respondon. Eble aliaj uzantoj povos helpi min plibone. Dankon, ĉiaokaze.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laŭ mia kompreno ambaŭ frazoj estas ĝustaj, kvankam [PIV](http://vortaro.net/#sole) kaj [ReVo](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/sol.html#sol.0e) rekomendas en tiu senco la adjektivan formon ***sola***:

> **sole**: Izolite, neakompanate aŭ nehelpate: *promeni **sol**e; malfeliĉo malofte venas **sol**e; baldaŭ montriĝis, ke nur la vorto
>   Esperanto, **sol**e aŭ kun aliaj vortoj, klare diferencigas nian
>   lingvon de aliaj*.
>
> **Rim.:** En tiu senco oni uzas prefere la adjektivan formon.

Eble la jenaj ekzemploj klarigas kial vortaroj donas tiun rekomendon:

1) Li venos sola dimanĉe.

2) Li venos sole dimanĉe.

La frazo 1) povas nur signifi, ke dimanĉe li venos sen akompano. Tamen, la frazo 2) povas havi du signifojn: ke dimanĉe li venos sen akompano, sed ankaŭ, ke nur en dimanĉo li venos. Por eviti ambiguecon, oni rekomendas la uzon de *sola* por *sen akompano* kaj la uzon de *sole* por *nur*.

La frazo *Vi timas iri sola* signifas, ke vi timas esti sola dum via irado. La frazo *Vi timas iri sole* signifas, ke vi timas iri en senakompana maniero dum via irado. La fina senco estas tre simila kaj ambaŭ ĝustas.

Comment: Dankegon pro via klarigo, Sinjor(in)o Vidamuzo.

Answer (score 1):

"Sola" kaj "sole" povas esti iomete konfuzivaj. Laŭ [PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/e-vortoj/uzo.html#i-8uc):

- *Mi iris sol**a** tien. = Mi iris tien sen akompano.* (adjektivo priskribas ĉi tie subjekton)
- *Mi iris sol**e** tien. = Mi iris nur tien.* (adverbo priskribas iun alian ol la subjekton; ĉar la adverbo estas ĝuste antaŭ "tien", oni supozas, ke la adverbo priskribas tiun vorton, t.e. direkton)

Comment: Dankegon pro via respondo, Sinjoro Metsäkallas.

Comment: _Eĉ ĉe Zamenhof oni trovas eraran uzon de ĵus: *Kial ni devas **ĵus** nun paroli pri li.* = ...ĝuste nun..._ ([PMEG: 14.2.6. Ĵus](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/e-vortecaj_vortetoj/tempaj/jhus.html)) ;-)

Comment: @Vidamuzo, ne temas pri tempo sed pri loko, sed mi konfesas, ke mi ofte fuŝas kun ĝuste kaj ĵus. Dankon.